# Tool/Algorithm for text comparision after every key hit

Tags: algorithm, text, time, comparison, typing

I am struggling to find a text comparison tool or algorithm that can compare an expected text against the current state of the text being typed.
I will have an experimentee typewrite a text that he has in front of his eyes. My idea is to compare the current state of the text against the expected text whenever something is typed. That way I want to find out when and what the subject does wrong (I also want to find errors that are not in the resulting text but were in the intermediate text for some time).
Can someone point me in a direction?

**Update #1**
I have access to the typing data in a csv format:
This is example output data of me typing "foOBar". Every line has the form (timestamp, Key, Press/Release)

```
17293398.576653,F,P
17293398.6885,F,R
17293399.135282,LeftShift,P
17293399.626881,LeftShift,R
17293401.313254,O,P
17293401.391732,O,R
17293401.827314,LeftShift,P
17293402.073046,O,P
17293402.184859,O,R
17293403.178612,B,P
17293403.301748,B,R
17293403.458137,LeftShift,R
17293404.966193,A,P
17293405.077869,A,R
17293405.725405,R,P
17293405.815159,R,R
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: The project is in c++ but i would appreciate a solution in any language.

Comment: Reading input "live" without having the user to press `enter` in C++ depends **a lot** on the OS and the terminal used... So what OS are you using?

Comment: In fact I will have a csv file with key names and a corresponding timestamp. I could recreate the text out of this data or use the csv directly. I also have access to the full text after each change.

Comment: Ah - so you don't need to compare *"after every key hit"* but you have record of the text after every key was hit and you want to compare that instead?

Comment: Yes. It would be a nice-to-have if it could be done on the run in c++, but I have all the data to do it after the experiment in any language as well.

Comment: Can you add an Input/Output example, please?

Comment: Added Output example.

Comment: Alright so given that *csv* file what do you want to do?

Comment: I have an expected text and someone who typewrites this text into a text field. Now I want to find out which characters were wrong and at what time that wrong characters were typed.

Comment: Isn't this trivial once you have that *csv* file as input? You can compare every character to the i-th character of the expected text and if that match you proceed, otherwise you found the wrong character

Comment: Not at all. People use backspaces and can move to the left and to the right with their cursor. Some errors are left in the text and will shift around all your characters.

Comment: Alright, now I understand the problem... We'll this looks pretty laborious to start from scrach. Would you mind a Python solution?

Comment: As mentioned above I would appreciate a solution in any language. This is not me asking any of you to implement this for me. This is just me asking for a tool or algorithm name. I can program myself and you have better things to do I guess.

Answer (score 0):

### In Python

Given your input *csv* file (I called it `keyboard_records.csv`)

```
17293398.576653,F,P
17293398.6885,F,R
17293399.135282,LeftShift,P
17293399.626881,LeftShift,R
17293401.313254,O,P
17293401.391732,O,R
17293401.827314,LeftShift,P
17293402.073046,O,P
17293402.184859,O,R
17293403.178612,B,P
17293403.301748,B,R
17293403.458137,LeftShift,R
17293404.966193,A,P
17293405.077869,A,R
17293405.725405,R,P
17293405.815159,R,R
```

The following code does the following:

1. Read its content and store it in a list named `steps`
2. For each `step` in `steps` recognizes what happened and

   - If it was a `shift` press or release sets a flag (`shift_on`) accordingly
   - If it was an arrow pressed moves the `cursor` (index of `current` where we insert characters) – if it the cursor is at the start or at the end of the string it shouldn't move, that's why those `min()` and `max()`
   - If it was a letter/number/symbol it adds it in `curret` at `cursor` position and increments `cursor`

Here you have it

```
import csv

steps = [] # list of all actions performed by user
expected = "Hello"

with open("keyboard.csv") as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        steps.append((float(row[0]), row[1], row[2]))

# Now we parse the information
current = [] # text written by the user
shift_on = False # is shift pressed
cursor = 0 # where is the cursor in the current text
for step in steps:
    time, key, action = step
    if key == 'LeftShift':
        if action == 'P':
            shift_on = True
        else:
            shift_on = False
        continue
    if key == 'LeftArrow' and action == 'P':
        cursor = max(0, cursor-1)
        continue
    if key == 'RightArrow' and action == 'P':
        cursor = min(len(current), cursor+1)
        continue
    if action == 'P':
        if shift_on is True:
            current.insert(cursor, key.upper())
        else:
            current.insert(cursor, key.lower())
        cursor += 1
        # Now you can join current into a string
        # and compare current with expected
        print(''.join(current)) # printing current (just to see what's happening)
    else:
        # What to do when a key is released?
        # Depends on your needs...
        continue
```

To compare `current` and `expected` have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare%20strings).

**Note:** by playing around with the code above and a few more flags you can make it recognize also symbols. This will depend on your keyboard. In mine `Shift + 6 = &`, `AltGr + E = €` and `Ctrl + Shift + AltGr + è = {`. I think this is a good point to start.

---

### Update

Comparing 2 texts isn't a difficult task and you can [find tons](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=compare%20strings) of pages on the web [about it](https://www.google.com/search?q=compare%20strings).
Anyway I wanted to present you an object oriented approach to the problem, so I added the `compare` part that I previously omitted in the first solution.

This is still a rough code, without primary controls over the input. But, as you asked, this is *pointing you in a direction*.

```
class UserText:
    # Initialize UserText:
    #  - empty text
    #  - cursor at beginning
    #  - shift off
    def __init__(self, expected):
        self.expected = expected
        self.letters = []
        self.cursor = 0
        self.shift = False
    # compares a and b and returns a
    # list containing the indices of
    # mismatches between a and b
    def compare(a, b):
        err = []
        for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))):
            if a[i] != b[i]:
                err.append(i)
        return err
    # Parse a command given in the
    # form (time, key, action)
    def parse(self, command):
        time, key, action = command
        output = ""
        if action == 'P':
            if key == 'LeftShift':
                self.shift = True
            elif key == 'LeftArrow':
                self.cursor = max(0, self.cursor - 1)
            elif key == 'RightArrow':
                self.cursor = min(len(self.letters), self.cursor + 1)
            else:
                # Else, a letter/number was pressed. Let's
                # add it to self.letters in cursor position
                if self.shift is True:
                    self.letters.insert(self.cursor, key.upper())
                else:
                    self.letters.insert(self.cursor, key.lower())
                self.cursor += 1
                ########## COMPARE WITH EXPECTED ##########
                output += "Expected: \t" + self.expected + "\n"
                output += "Current: \t" + str(self) + "\n"
                errors = UserText.compare(str(self), self.expected[:len(str(self))])
                output += "\t\t"
                i = 0
                for e in errors:
                    while i != e:
                        output += " "
                        i += 1
                    output += "^"
                    i += 1
                output += "\n[{} errors at time {}]".format(len(errors), time)
                return output


        else:
            if key == 'LeftShift':
                self.shift = False
        return output

    def __str__(self):
        return "".join(self.letters)


import csv
steps = [] # list of all actions performed by user
expected = "foobar"

with open("keyboard.csv") as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        steps.append((float(row[0]), row[1], row[2]))

# Now we parse the information
ut = UserText(expected)
for step in steps:
    print(ut.parse(step))
```

The output for the `csv` file above was:

```
Expected:       foobar
Current:        f

[0 errors at time 17293398.576653]

Expected:       foobar
Current:        fo

[0 errors at time 17293401.313254]


Expected:       foobar
Current:        foO
                  ^
[1 errors at time 17293402.073046]

Expected:       foobar
Current:        foOB
                  ^^
[2 errors at time 17293403.178612]


Expected:       foobar
Current:        foOBa
                  ^^
[2 errors at time 17293404.966193]

Expected:       foobar
Current:        foOBar
                  ^^
[2 errors at time 17293405.725405]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what i asked for. You just wrote a tool that reconstruts the text out of the keystrokes. I asked for a tool that gives me the errors that are in each intermediate version of a text that someone typewrites. Is my question so unclear?

Comment: Well I was sure the "difficult" part was building the pattern key by key... Once you have it, comparing it to the expected text is trivial. That's why I wrote *"Now you you can join [...] and compare current with expected"*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own question around a year ago. Now i have time to share it with you:

In their 2003 paper 'Metrics for text entry research: An evaluation of MSD and KSPC, and a new unified error metric', R. William Soukoreff and I. Scott MacKenzie propose three major new metrics: 'total error rate', 'corrected error rate' and 'not corrected error rate'. These metrics have become well established since the publication of this paper. These are exaclty the metrics i was looking for.

If you are trying to do something similiar to what i did, e.g. compare the writing performance on different input devices this is the way to go.